# Showing that the system of a planar curve is Lipschitz in y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

This question below, which was given in an exam, goes as follows:

> A planar curve $y(x)$ is such that its curvature, 
>   $$k(x)=y''(x)/(1+y'(x)^2)^{3/2}$$ is equal to its height $y(x)$. Write
>   the equation as a pair of first order equations, and show that the
>   system is Lipschitz in $y$.

Now my working is as follows:
Let $$u=y, v=y'$$ 
$$\implies u'=v, v'=(1+v^2)^{3/2}u$$
which answers the first part of the question. Now to show that it is Lipschitz in $y$:
$$|u_1'-u_2'|=|v_1-v_2|\leq |u_1-u_2|+|v_1-v_2|$$

My problem is for the second part:
\begin{align}
|v_1'-v_2'|=&|(1+v_1^2)^{3/2}u_1-(1+v_2^2)^{3/2}u_2|\\
=&|(1+v_1^2)^{3/2}u_1-(1+v_1^2)^{3/2}u_2+(1+v_1^2)^{3/2}u_2-(1+v_2^2)^{3/2}u_2|\\
\leq &|1+v_1^2|^{3/2}|u_1-u_2|+|u_2|||(1+v_1^2)^{3/2}-(1+v_2^2)^{3/2}|
\end{align}

Now I can always bound the first term, but for the second term, I have no idea how to simplify in such a way to get $K|v_1-v_2|$ for some constant $K$. Any hints? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: By Lipschitz in $y$ do you mean in $u$ in your notation? Or do you mean a bound of the form $K(|u_1 - u_2| + | v_1 -v_2|)$?

Comment: Yes, exactly like the latter

Comment: That it is locally Lipschitz follows from the differentiability of the right sides, thus uniqueness of solutions follows. As you found, this is not globally Lipschitz. Integration after multiplication by $2y'$ gives $C=y^2+(1+y'^2)^{-1/2}$ as first integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply either a mean value theorem or the binomial theorem as in
$$
(1+v_1^2)^{3/2}-(1+v_2^2)^{3/2}=\frac{(1+v_1^2)^3-(1+v_2^2)^3}{(1+v_1^2)^{3/2}+(1+v_2^2)^{3/2}}
\\
=\frac{(v_1-v_2)(v_1+v_2)\Bigl((1+v_1^2)^2+(1+v_1^2)(1+v_2^2)+(1+v_2^2)^2\Bigr)}{(1+v_1^2)^{3/2}+(1+v_2^2)^{3/2}}
$$
where you get the simple difference as factors and can bound the other factors.